# No keypress event for asp textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i need to work on keypress event of asp textbox but keypress event not available for the asp textbox. Is there alternative available for this problem? Plz help!

Comment: Can you tell us your specific needs in some scenario, so that we can provide particular problem solution.

Answer (score 4):

Make use of keypress event of javascript + textbox

and call the serverside function by using ajax or using pagemthods.

```
.cs file
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]

   public static string docall()
   {
      return "Hello";
   }

.aspx file

<script type="text/javascript">
      function btnAccept_onclic() {
          PageMethods.docall(onSuccess, onFailure);
      }

  function onSuccess(result) {
          alert(result);
      }


      function onFailure(error) {
          alert(error);
      } 

</script>
```

check this : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/04/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'" + Button1.ClientID + "')");
```

The code-behind generates the following:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" onkeypress="return clickButton(event,'Button1')"  />
```

This causes the web control `Button1` to be clicked when the enter key is hit inside `TextBox1`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

1. Just make TextBox's `AutoPostBack` `True`
   (To do this, click TextBox then press <kbd>F4</kbd>. Then in properties, make AutoPostBack True)
2. And then use TextBox `OnTextChanged` event.
   (To do this, select Design View. Then click the TextBox again. Then click events tab (the Events button is in the upper side) and double click TextChanged event)

Answer (score 0):

This is help for you for onkey press and allow numeric values

function fncInputNumericValuesOnly() {
        if (!(event.keyCode == 45 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 48 || event.keyCode == 49 || event.keyCode == 50 || event.keyCode == 51 || event.keyCode == 52 || event.keyCode == 53 || event.keyCode == 54 || event.keyCode == 55 || event.keyCode == 56 || event.keyCode == 57 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 16)) {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    }

```
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtRphone" runat="server" CssClass="NormalTextBox" onkeypress="fncInputNumericValuesOnly()"
                                MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
```