# TextBox KeyDown Event in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find KeyDown event in Asp.net like windows application.. i have several TextBox after press enter inside textbox i want to focus on save button how can i achieve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No keypress event for asp textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865287/no-keypress-event-for-asp-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this! You can use asp panel for it.

Paste you textbox and button html code inside asp panel and than set panel's property of `DefaultButton` to your button name.

Comment: its Working for only Enter Key only.. How about other keys...?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this from "ASP.NET" code (that is, C#) because the `TextBox` doesn't exist on the server when the user is interacting with it.  What you need to do instead is wire up client-side behaviour using JavaScript that can respond to textbox events raised in the user's browser.

Comment: Only if all the answers in this forum had informative explanations like this one had: "... because the TextBox doesn't exist on the server when the user is interacting with it."

Answer (score 3):

It is suggested to use javascript for this purpose.

```
Example:-

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

     function handleEnter (obj, event) 
     {        
     var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;        
     if (keyCode == 13) 
     {                    
        document.getElementById(obj).click();
                    return false;        
     }        
     else  {
           return true;   
            }   
     } 
</script> 

Relevant codes


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return handleEnter('" + Button1.ClientID + "', event)");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefaultButton option.
 or
You can use JavaScript functions for OnKeyDown function.