# How to detect postback caused by enter key in textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, textbox, key, enter, textchanged

A `TextBox` in a web application will cause a `TextChanged` event when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, but only if the text **has changed**.

If the text **has not changed** when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, a postback still occurs, but the `TextChanged` event does not.

I'm wondering if it is possible to determine that <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed in a textbox and caused the postback, ie. is there something like the following?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sender.reasonControlName == "MyTextBox" &&
            sender.reasonControlKey == keyEnter) {
        handleEnterKey();
    }
}
```

ASP.Net 4

Note, this is not a question about how to disable the postback caused by ENTER key in a TextBox in a web application, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903/asp-net-page-enter-key-causing-post-back)

There is also a workaround using a panel and DefaultButton [stackoverflow.com/questions/12072281](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072281/textbox-keydown-event-in-asp-net), but this seems like a bit of a cludge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of the TextBox where <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed can be stored in a hidden field:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" onkeydown="keyPressed(event, 'txtBox1');" ... />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server" onkeydown="keyPressed(event, 'txtBox2');" ... />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenEnterPressed" runat="server" />

<script>
    function keyPressed(e, id) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById('hiddenEnterPressed').value = id;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note: The `onkeydown` event could be defined as `keyPressed(event, this.id)` but the (possibly) mangled ID would then be saved in the hidden field; hard-coding the original ID can make things simpler.

The TextBox control can be retrieved in code-behind:

```
Control mainCtrl = Master.FindControl("MainContent");
TextBox txtBox = mainCtrl.FindControl(hiddenEnterPressed.Value) as TextBox;
```

The hidden field should be reset on each postback:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    hiddenEnterPressed.Value = "";
}
```

Comment: @ConnersFan That workaround seems to be more work than putting the field in a panel and using `DefaultButton` to trigger a postback, but it is useful to have it documented here all the same.