# Reference to system.web.ui not system.web.forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keypress

I have a problem.

I want capture the event KeyPress in a filter.

```
<div class="row rowMarginTop ">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilterCategory" runat="server" Visible="True">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFilterCategory" Text="Rechercher une catégorie"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFilterCategory"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFilterCategory" Text="Rechercher" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

But in my code behind i doesn't found KeyPress

```
Protected Sub txtFilterCategory_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As Global.System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtFilterCategory.KeyPress
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txbFilterProduit.Text) Then
        Session("FilterExpression") = txbFilterProduit.Text
    End If

    RadTreeListF07.Rebind()
End Sub
```

I think it's because for my txtFilterCategory it said "Protected WithEvents txtFilterCategory As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox Contrôle txtFilterCategory"

so it's not a reference of system.windows.form and i think it's my problem.

my import are

```
   Imports System.Windows.Forms
    Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Web
```

So my question it's what's the way to catch the KeyPress in my codebehind?

Sorry for my english i'm french guy and a beginner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No keypress event for asp textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865287/no-keypress-event-for-asp-textbox)

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't. You can use javascript or you could postback for every keypress (but that is probably not a good idea).